# Why can I still run Vim in the Terminal if I removed it?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, vim, package-management

I'm on Ubuntu 11.04. I removed Vim (7.3) using Software Center, so why can I still it?

If I type `vim` in the Terminal, then Vim starts running. The executables in `/usr/local/bin` weren't deleted.

Comment: The directory /usr/local is not maintained by package managers, it is reserved for the local administrator.  See the FHS standard:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard

Answer (score 4):

The system might have vim installed by default, and the version you installed via Software Center is just a newer version and one that gets automatic updates. If you want to see where vim is and get rid of it, run this command in the terminal:

```
which -a vim
```

This will show you all the locations that the vim executable is found in. You can remove them if you want to get rid of vim completely (Which you shouldn't really need to do, and isn't advised unless there is some reason you absolutely *have* to).

Comment: *> if you want to get rid of vim completely.* — which you really shouldn't unless you *need* to :P

Answer (score 1):

Ok, to be honest I don't know what happened when I installed Vim. I didn't check if it was already installed.

I used Mercurial to download it from a repository (http://vim.googlecode.com/hg/). I'm new at using Linux. I just followed the instructions that are at the Vim's website. I typed in the terminal the same commands:

```
hg clone https://vim.googlecode.com/hg/ vim
cd vim/src
make
```

Nothing more, nothing less.

This created a directory in **/home/emmanuel** called Vim, and compiled the code in that same directory.

When I type `which -a vim` in the terminal it shows `/usr/local/bin/vim`

I wanted to remove it for two reasons:

1. I can't find the .vimrc file to change the configuration and
2. I want to install `vim-gnome` hoping it is a little bit more user friendly.

What do you recommend me to do, specially with the files at **/home/emmanuel/vim**????